# Spreadsheet Gear #value when result.Number contains the correct return value

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I am working on a project porting VBA code to C# for Spreadsheet Gear. My team has successfully ported around 150 custom Excel Add-in functions.  For one of the functions, our regression spreadsheet returns #value for 4 out of 148 function calls, with the remainder returning the expected result.  When I step through the code, everything functions as expected and the correct result gets written to result.Number, but resolves to #value in Spreadsheet Gear.  I'm totally baffled!  Please help me - I don't even know where to start.

The end of the function is as follows:

```
if (retval < 0)
{
     result.Text = UtilFuncs.ErrorNum(retval);
}
else
{
     result.Number = retval;
}
```

`retval` contains the correct result returned from a call to a separate DLL. And when I hover over `result.Number`, it also contains the correct result.  But I get a #value.

I can provide more code if necessary.  My big question is why it works for all but 4 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a more concrete example, it's about impossible to provide a definitive answer to this.  I'll take a shot in the dark, though.

If you use [IArguments](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.IArguments_members.html) methods like IArguments.[GetNumber](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.IArguments~GetNumber.html)(...),
 [GetLogical](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.IArguments~GetLogical.html)(...), etc., to access your custom function's arguments, you might read through the documentation for these.  For instance, see the following remark for [GetLogical](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.IArguments~GetLogical.html)(...):

- Non-logical arguments are converted to a logical value if possible.
  Otherwise, false is returned by this method, and **an internal flag is
  set indicating that an error has occurred, causing the result of the
  formula to be an error**.

So if you pass in a non-boolean value into an argument where you are expecting a Boolean, your function may end up having this internal "error" flag being set and so result in a #VALUE! error being displayed for this cell, regardless of what you set the result object at the end of your method.

If this is the case, you can use the IArguments.[ClearError](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.IArguments~ClearError.html)(...) method to clear the error.

Comment: Thanks! I used the IArguments.ClearError() method and I now get the expected result.  It appears that all of the arguments are being retrieved using the correct GetNumber or GetText.